# NFS server doesn't start if I remove network interface

Tags: networking, centos, nfs

I don't know if this is a bug or feature, but I had to remove a network interface from one of my server and since it won'T be needed anymore it won't have any replacement. However, since I've removed it, the NFS server doesn't start at all. If I put the network card back, it boots without any error. Also if I put it back, but turn it off via `ONBOOT=NO` in the ifcfg-eth2, it doesn't load again so..... is this now a bug or a feature? Either it is, how can I solve the issue?

I'm sure I don't have to mention, that removing the eth2 interface wouldn't end up in a system fail in terms of the system architecture, the servers who needs to mount the shared folders are still can reach out to the nfs server. I'm able to log in via them after all. Eth2 was a temporary interface with internet connection on order to install applications the easy way and not just copying every rpm package thru 3 servers in order to reach the file server.

```
sudo systemctl status nfs-server

● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
           └─order-with-mounts.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)

dec 04 09:28:22 fileserver-2 systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on nfs-server.service/start
dec 04 09:28:22 fileserver-2 systemd[1]: Found dependency on var-nfsshare.mount/start
dec 04 09:28:22 fileserver-2 systemd[1]: Found dependency on nfs-server.service/start
dec 04 09:28:22 fileserver-2 systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job var-nfsshare.mount/start
```

Regards:
Bert

UPDATE:
NFS Server requires all your NICs to be in the status UP. I might think this is a kind of a bug because if I remove the NIC from the server hardware vise + I also remove it from the system (nmcli con del eth2) I get the network service a status OK plus I can see all my interfaces up. Somehow NFS-Server stucks in the state like if I had one interface down still. Even despite the fact I don't have the corresponding network  mentioned in any of the configs, especially in the exports file.

What I think that nfs-server doesn't re-check the current configuration of the system at every start, only at install time. However it is still unclear to me why doesn't it re-read it then when I reinstall nfs-server.

What do you guys think? Do I say stupid things or this makes sence?

Comment: Maybe there is a network dependency on the nfs service? Look at `systemctl list-dependencies` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. Maybe it will give you some inside.

Comment: Unfortunately I had no time to debug the test system, so I had to reinstall it already. But when I'll have some time I'll replicate the issue and come back with the sollution if there is. But I've checked everything that is possible sysadmin vise and couldn't find a single line that would refer to the missing NIC. However, The service had a dependency to wait for the network service to be up. Even tho I've deleted the interface the proper way, maybe the service was somehow still missing it and therefore it never came to a static up status and that blocked maybe the nfs server to start.